# How do I print out Chef default.rb values to stdout?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe

I want to read out some urls and versions numbers from this Chef default attribute file:

https://github.com/aws/aws-parallelcluster-cookbook/blob/develop/attributes/default.rb

I know I can use a `grep`, `sed`, `awk` solution but those are usually more brittle and I don't have control over this file. I just want to be able to download it and parse out the values I need.

An example solution could be print out `default.rb` as JSON to stdout and parse it with `jq` or create a ruby script that prints it out.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I want a way to read data out of the default.rb file, IE I want to grab version data/urls out of default.rb and use it programmatically for something else.

It would be nice to be able to do

```
require('default.rb')

puts default['cfncluster']['nvidia']['driver_version']
```

This would print out the value from line 68 to stdout and I could then do anything I wanted with it. This above is my failed attempt to us ruby. This method fails, it says that default is not defined. I am not a ruby person maybe there is a way to load it in without getting that error message.

Any suggestions are appreciated. If you can print everything out as JSON using some chef cli that is fine too. I can parse what I need out of it.

Comment: would you like to print the stdout as a part of the cookbook execution?

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify whether you'd like to do it during chef-client.

although it is not recommended, you can achieve it by usuin `eval()`. for instance:

```rb
# foo.rb
default['foo']['bar'] = "baz"
```

```rb
# read.rb
default = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key]={}}
eval(File.read("./foo.rb"))
puts default['foo']['bar']
```

```sh
$ ruby test.rb
baz
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I appreciate you taking the time to answer this. I need a way to extracts values out of the `default.rb` file. I don't care what method it is. As long as it works.

Comment: I tried you example (with value keys from `default.rb`) I got this error message: undefined local variable or method `node' for main:Object.

Comment: I added in this line node =  Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key]={}} which got it past the error now it is giving me this error: Undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass it is coming from the eval line.

Comment: @jlonganecker: if you look closely at the file you shared, then you can see that it has more variables then just `default`. my snippet deals with the simplies case.

Comment: In the original question I shared the link to the file directly. You can download it and try out solutions. That is why I shared it. If you don't have the time to figure it out, no worries. I may have to learn some ruby :).